# only default controller is loading for all request - Critical

Tags: codeigniter

My codeigniter project is in live.
I have two copies of it. One in the root and another in a subfolder.
Both are configered to work normal.

The root copy if the one which was made after testing in a subfolder.
While running from the a subfolder all worked well.

But when copied to the root folder the default controller is loading for all requests.
But were as in subfolders and in other servers it is working well.

It is like the following
A true copy in root folder like sitename.com
and another true copy in a subfolder like sitename.com/abc

when requesting like this sitename.com/gallery the default controller is loaded instead of gallery controller.

When i tried like this sitename.com/index.php/gallery/ then it worked well... 
but sitename.com/gallery/ is showing only the default controller. that is the index page.

here is my htaccess...

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag short_open_tag on

RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|static|font|xml|flash|galleryimages|htc|store|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The server is 
Linux barracuda.elinuxservers.com 2.6.27.18-21 #1 SMP Tue Aug 25 18:13:37 UTC 2009 i686 
PHP Version 5.2.9

Answer (score 0):

What is your $config['uri_protocol'] set to? Just try all the values and one will work in the end.